# Matching emails format using R

Tags: r, pattern-matching

I was having an intro class at datacamp.com and ran into a problem.

Goal: find right emails using `grep`. "Right emails" defined by having an "@", end with ".edu").

Emails vector:

```
emails <- c("john.doe@ivyleague.edu", "education@world.gov", "dalai.lama@peace.org", 
        "invalid.edu", "quant@bigdatacollege.edu", "cookie.monster@sesame.tv")
```

I was thinking of

```
grep("@*\\.edu$",emails)
```

and it gave me

[1] 1 4 5

because I thought "*" matches "multiple characters". Later I found that it doesn't work like that.

Turned out the right code is

```
grep("@.*\\.edu$",emails)
```

I googled some documentation and only have a vague sense of how to get the correct answer. Can someone explain how exactly R match the right emails? Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: The regular expressions are described in documentation just like you wrote. Which part of it exactly is the problem?

Comment: @JakubKania I think I just don't understand why I added "@" into the pattern, but "invalid.edu" is still matched. I hope I made myself clear (I'm still learning English).

Comment: * means zero or more so you're initial regex looked for zero or more @ characters hence 'invalid.edu' is matched.

Comment: Because . matches any character so now you're looking for a string that contains one @, any characters one or more times and ends with .edu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've already been advised the using the asterisk quantifier wasn't giving you the specificity you needed, so use the "+" quantifier, which forces at least one such match. I decided to make the problem more complex by adding some where there were duplicated at-signs:

```
emails <- c("john.doe@@ivyleague.edu", "education@@world.gov", "dalai.lama@peace.org", 
"invalid.edu", "quant@bigdatacollege.edu", "cookie.monster@sesame.tv")


grep( "^[^@]+@[^@]+\\.edu$", emails)
#[1] 5
```

That uses the regex character-class structure where items inside flankking square-brackets are taken as literals except when there is an initial up-caret ("^"), in which case it is the negation of the character class, i.e. in this case any character except "@". This will also exclude situations where the at-sign is the first character. Thanks to KonradRudolph who pointed out that adding `"^"` as the first character in the pattern (which signifies the point just before the first character of a potential match) would prevent allowing Items with an initial "@@" from being matched.